# Rails: Titlecase Only Capitalizes First Word in f.label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string

The first line of code does what I want, the second only capitalizes the first word:

```
<%= the_label = "Time_Balance".titlecase %><br />
<%= f.label "Time_Balance".titlecase %><br />
```

I want to titlecase the input label, but I just can't manage it.

This also doesn't work:

```
<%= the_label = "Time_Balance".titlecase %><br />
<%= f.label the_label %><br />
```

Nor does this:

```
<%= the_label = "Time_Balance" %><br />
<%= f.label the_label.titlecase %><br />
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

try this.

```
<%= f.label :time_balance, "Time Balance" %> <br />
```

Label expects the first argument to be the method_name on the object the form is for,  and defaults to just using it, unless you specify it explicitly as part of the second argument which is content/options.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation as well as the solution!

Comment: Mine looks like this: `.col-md-2.col-form-label= label_tag(name='First Second')`

What do I do on this case?

Comment: Apparently f.label also down cases everything.  I was able to preserve case by passing the optional argument like so:  `<%= f.label :my_text, @question.my_text %>`.

Comment: So weird. I had a label with 3 sentences, and couldn't figure out when the second 2 sentences were being downcased. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment because of my rep. To answer webaholik's question, you can use label_tag in this case:

```
<%= label_tag :time_balance, "Time Balance" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

**F! What if I can't use "f." ?**

..such as a secondary filter that doesn't reference a valid attribute

```
<%= label :time_balance, "Time Balance" %> <br />
```