# haml converting label_tag name to lowercase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have haml code as follows:

```
.col-md-2.col-form-label= label_tag(name='First Second')
```

The output looks like: `First second` instead of `First Second`.

How can I make it without using `css` to look like `First Second`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Titlecase Only Capitalizes First Word in f.label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793681/titlecase-only-capitalizes-first-word-in-f-label)

Comment: I already looked into that. The way it's written is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the `content_or_options` within the second argument of `label_tag`. Documentation found [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/label_tag)

This would be the update:

```
label_tag('First Second', 'First Second')
```

Within the `label_tag` method, [humanize](https://apidock.com/rails/String/humanize) is called on the `name` if no content is provided, making `Second` lowercase.

Comment: Awesome ! Thank you so much for the answer. I have decided to go with `label_tag('name', 'First Second')` to not repeat the same thing and let everyone know it's a `name`. What do you think about that ?

Comment: That seems more appropriate :)